# How does this code for calculating mean and standard deviation work?

Tags: ocaml

I don't quite understand the following code which calculates the mean and standard deviation of a list of numbers:

```
let stats l =
  let rec helper rest n sum sum_squares =
    match rest with
    | [] -> let nf = float_of_int n in
      (sum /. nf, sqrt (sum_squares /. nf))
    | h :: t ->
      helper t (n+1) (sum+.h) (sum_squares +. (h*.h)) in
  helper l 0 0.0 0.0;;
```

For example:

```
let (mean, sd) = stats [1.; 2.; 3.; 4.; 5.];;
```

To which the interpreter responds

```
val mean : float = 3.
val sd : float = 3.3166247903554
```

In

```
      helper t (n+1) (sum+.h) (sum_squares +. (h*.h)) in
  helper l 0 0.0 0.0;;
```

What do `in` and `helper l 0 0.0 0.0` mean here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition breaks down into pieces like this

```
let stats l =
    let rec helper rest n sum sum_squares =
        (* Definition of helper *)
    in
    helper l 0 0.0 0.0
```

The keyword `in` doesn't mean anything by itself. It goes with `let`. The `in` you're talking about goes with the `let` that defines `helper`. So in English it's saying **`let`** `helper` be defined as the following **`in`** `helper l 0 0.0 0.0`.

The expression `helper l 0 0.0 0.0` is a call to the `helper` function defined by the `let`.

So in even simpler English it says "define helper as the following function, then call helper with the parameters `l 0 0.0 0.0`."